# How do I fix an error regarding filtering variables in R?

Tags: r, filter

I have a data set containing climate and soil variables within certain biomes and ecoregions. I want to perform an independent Wilcoxon test on the difference between the variables in tropical areas and subtropical areas, filtering by the biome and ecoregion variables, but I keep getting an error:

```r
data2 <- filter(data, biome == "Tropical")
data3 <- filter(data, biome == "Subtropical")
data4 <- filter(data2, ecoregion == "Tropical and subtropical grasslands, savannas and shrublands")
data5 <- filter(data3, ecoregion == "Tropical and subtropical grasslands, savannas and shrublands")
```

```
> data2 <- filter(data, biome == "Tropical")
Error in attr(data, "tsp") <- c(start, end, frequency) : 
  object is not a matrix
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of `data`? Did you intent to use `dplyr::filter` (expects a data.frame) or `stats::filter` (expects a time series), or `base::Filter` (expects vector, not capital `F`)? If you didn't attach `dplyr`, then you're using `stats::filter`

Comment: In what form would you like me to show you the data? I indeed did not attach dplyr should I do so?

Comment: [This question explains how to write a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1). You'll want to make a minimal dataset that reproduces your problem, and then use `dput` to generate a copy/pastable version

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do. If you want to use the "filter" function from the dplyr package, you either need to attach the package with `library(dplyr)` or refer to the package specifically with `dplyr::filter` (which means, the filter function from the dplyr package).